# Accessibility Issues with Site-Wide jQuery Audio Player

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, accessibility

I've been researching ways to use a jQuery music player site-wide without stopping playback when a new page is loaded. One of my possible options is to hide all of the content using CSS, and then display it when the page is selected.

Would doing this cause any accessibility issues or problems with SEO? What are the pros and cons to doing this?

Honestly, I'm running out of options, and if this doesn't work... I may have to use frames. Yuck!

As an aside, I've read that I could also use AJAX to dynamically change the URL, so I suppose that's also an option. (Can PHP do the same?)

**ALSO,** I don't plan on auto-playing the music, but rather just have it available for the user to play whenever they'd like.

An example of how my player would look and function can be found at: [www.reverbnation.com](http://www.reverbnation.com).

Comment: You can use an iframe to ensure the music player continues playing. The solution you suggested just sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I've read so many articles against using frames, though. Could you speak to why that sounds like a bad idea?

Comment: SEO would be compromised if your site would then have more than 1 <h1>, <h2> tag. Plus, your lone HTML file would contain several pages worth of semantic markup. You could use an AJAX request to access the new page and spit its contents into the current window.

Comment: Is PHP also a viable option? Or at least similar?

Comment: I don't believe so, but my knowledge of PHP is limited.

Comment: "SEO would be compromised if your site would then have more than 1 <h1>, <h2> tag." This is incorrect unless we are talking about SEO techniques from 5+ years ago. Using multiple `<h1>` will have very little effect on SEO unless you are using like 20 a page or writing a paragraph and wrapping it in an h1. OP: I'd drop the player completely, this was something done pre-2000...

Comment: Considering I'm a composer, dropping the player isn't an option. Somehow I must make my music available to the users of my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-playing of content can cause accessibility problems in general, as it can interfere with a screenreader, disorientating the user. For example, see http://www.prettysimple.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/07/autoplaying-videos/

Comment: I added a response to this in my question.